# get_absolute_url creates blank link

Tags: django

get_absolute_url doesn't create url. Clicking in title of the post must lead to detail of the post. While I manually create url in address bar as blog/2020/1/3/check-text, it works. What could be the possible problem? Is it something to do with python version?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, 
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() # the default manager
    published = PublishedManager() # our custom manager

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)        

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args = [
                            self.publish.year,
                            self.publish.month,
                            self.publish.day,
                            self.slug,
                        ])
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger,\
                                             EmptyPage
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post
from .forms import EmailPostForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', 
          views.post_detail,
          name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:post_id>/share/',
          views.post_share, name='post_share'),
]
```

list.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock%}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
            {{ post.title }}
        </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="date">
        Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- {% include '../pagination.html' with page=posts %} -->
    {% include '../pagination.html' with page=page_obj %}
{% endblock %}
```

detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p class="date">
        Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'blog:post_share' post.id %}">
            Share this post
        </a>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

[see href is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OrjR.png)

Comment: you have a typo in templates correct it to get_absolute_url, remove the double underscore

Comment: that didn't fix the problem

Comment: this queryset = Post.published.all() giving you any output?

Comment: yeah, it does return the title of the post's: <QuerySet [<Post: NOpe>, <Post: wassup Dude>]>